# Add new key/value pair into JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a result from my MySQL DB that I'm json encoding in PHP, the result looks like 
:

```
[
    {
        "id": "8488",
        "name": "Tenby",
        "area": "Area1"
    },
    {
        "id": "8489",
        "name": "Harbour",
        "area": "Area1"
    },
    {
        "id": "8490",
        "name": "Mobius",
        "area": "Area1"
    }
]
```

What I would like to do is to add a new key/value pair to that JSON so that it will be :

```
[
    {
        "id": "8488",
        "name": "Tenby",
        "area": "Area1",
        "image": "1278.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "8489",
        "name": "Harbour",
        "area": "Area1",
        "image": "1279.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "8490",
        "name": "Mobius",
        "area": "Area1",
        "image": "1280.jpg"
    }
]
```

So how can I do that in PHP?

Comment: `json_decode(json, true)` -> `push element` -> `json_encode` -> done. :)

Comment: Hi, can you please be more clear, I want to add a different image to each collection of keys I mean (add a defferent image to each "id","name","area")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<?php

$data[0]['id']="8488";
$data[0]['name']="Tenby";
$data[0]['area']="Area1";

$data[1]['id']="8489";
$data[1]['name']="Harbour";
$data[1]['area']="Area1";

$data[2]['id']="8490";
$data[2]['name']="Mobius";
$data[2]['area']="Area1";

echo json_encode($data)."<br/>";

/*Add Image element (or whatever) into the array according to your needs*/

$data[0]['image']="1278.jpg";
$data[1]['image']="1279.jpg";
$data[2]['image']="1280.jpg";

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using foreach(). Or give any other dynamic method to do the same.

Comment: @Suyog You can use any loop but that's according to your requirement & Condition.

Comment: How to do it if you have objects and array in same json

Answer (score 4):

PHP is not very good with JSON. Its best to convert from JSON to Array to do this - what @egig has also recommended.

Example code:

```
$temp = json_decode($json);
$temp[] = new data, whatever you want to add...;
$json = json_encode($temp);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

hu?

the result of the db query will be an array or an object...
add the additional entry to that data, only encode after every necessary data manipulation is done

alternatives, but clumsy (horrible):

- `json_decode`, add stuff, `json_encode`
- build your additional data as a string, `str_replace` for example `"area": "Area1"` in your json string with `"area": "Area1", "image": "1278.jpg"`

but really:
output formatting like json_encode should only be done once you are sure that you have the whole output together and it is send out

Comment: The issue is that my DB result does not have an image data so I have to add the image to the result and the only way I see is turning it into json first before adding an image info for each result row if you want.

Comment: but you will have the db result as an array or an object first. PHP has a lot of functions to work with arrays and objects, but no real functions to work with JSON. From PHPs perspective, json data is a serialization of an array/object. The exact method depends on how you fetch the data...assuming you fetch the rows as associative array, you can simply add the image info as `$yourRowVar['image'] = 'imageX.jpg'`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe things have changed since then, but I know this will work at this current stage:-

So here is the JSON string:-

```
$strJSON = '[
  {
      "id": "8488",
      "name": "Tenby",
      "area": "Area1"
  },
  {
      "id": "8489",
      "name": "Harbour",
      "area": "Area1"
  },
  {
      "id": "8490",
      "name": "Mobius",
      "area": "Area1"
  }
]';
```

If this is still a string, then I would convert it into an object like this:-

```
$json = json_decode( $strJSON );
```

Now that it is in object format, to add my "image" keys with their values, I would then add them like it is shown below:-

```
$json[0]->image = "1278.jpg";
$json[1]->image = "1279.jpg";
$json[2]->image = "1280.jpg";
```

So then if I add the code below after the above code:-

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $json );
echo "</pre>";
```

We should then see it outputting on the page like so:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8488
            [name] => Tenby
            [area] => Area1
            [image] => 1278.jpg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8489
            [name] => Harbour
            [area] => Area1
            [image] => 1279.jpg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8490
            [name] => Mobius
            [area] => Area1
            [image] => 1280.jpg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

//$index = some value in array;

```
for($i=0;$i<count($index);$i++){
            $data[$i]->key = $index[$i];
        }
print $data;
```