# Why the key-value-pair won't be added?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to add a new key-value-pair at the end of every `users` element:

```
<?php
$json = '[
  {
    "date": "2014-10-09T17:38:19Z",
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "Peter",
        "age": 20
      },
      {
        "name": "Anne",
        "age": 25
      },
      {
        "name": "William",
        "age": 30
      }
    ]
  }
]';

addData ( $json );
function addData($json) {
    $obj = json_decode ( $json, true );
    foreach ( $obj as $items ) {
        foreach ( $items ['users'] as $users ) {
            $array = array (
                    "myKey" => "myValue" 
            );
            array_push ( $users, $array );
        }
    }
    $json = json_encode ( $obj );

    echo $json;
}
?>
```

So the new `json` should look like

```
[  
   {  
      "date":"2014-10-09T17:38:19Z",
      "users":[  
         {  
            "name":"Peter",
            "age":20,
            "myKey":"myValue"
         },
         {  
            "name":"Anne",
            "age":25,
            "myKey":"myValue"
         },
         {  
            "name":"William",
            "age":30,
            "myKey":"myValue"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Instead, I get my old `json` as an output, without the new key-value-pair.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new key/value pair into JSON in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447175/add-new-key-value-pair-into-json-in-php)

Comment: @Core972 not a duplicate.

Comment: Iterate the array by reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the manual about [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop
>   precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by
>   reference.

This way you can edit the values in the `$items` and the `$users` array.

I think you can do it like this:

```
addData ( $json );
function addData($json) {
    $obj = json_decode ( $json, true );
    foreach ( $obj as &$items ) {
        foreach ( $items ['users'] as &$users ) {
            $users["mykey"] = "myValue";
        }
    }
    $json = json_encode ( $obj );
    echo $json;
}
```

Will result in:

```
[{
    "date": "2014-10-09T17:38:19Z",
    "users": [{
        "name": "Peter",
        "age": 20,
        "mykey": "myValue"
    }, {
        "name": "Anne",
        "age": 25,
        "mykey": "myValue"
    }, {
        "name": "William",
        "age": 30,
        "mykey": "myValue"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Try to provide a bit more explanation as to what you are doing and why it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that foreach provides a copy of arrays not the actual array, so when you modify $users you are not modifying the $json variable like you think you are.   Try the following, I have changed name of variables etc for readability

```
<?php
$json = '[
  {
    "date": "2014-10-09T17:38:19Z",
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "Peter",
        "age": 20
      },
      {
        "name": "Anne",
        "age": 25
      },
      {
        "name": "William",
        "age": 30
      }
    ]
  }
]';

$updated = addData ( $json );
echo $updated;

function addData($json) {
    $ArrList = json_decode ( $json, true );

    foreach ( $ArrList['users'] as $userKey => $user ) {
            $array = array (
                    "myKey" => "myValue" 
             );
        $ArrList['users'][$userKey][] =  $array;
    }

    $json = json_encode ( $ArrList );

    return $json;
}
?>
```

The code above loops through your users array in your structure and keeps hold of the key in the foreach loop.  Then when we have the sturcture we want we update the origional array.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `$items` and `$users` arrays by reference, like so:

```
function addData($json) {

    $obj = json_decode ( $json, true );

    foreach ( $obj as &$items ) {
        foreach ( $items ['users'] as &$users ) {
            $users['myKey'] = 'myValue';
        }
    }
    $json = json_encode ( $obj );

    echo $json;
}
```