# How to add in digits per json objects wih php

Tags: php

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxW3G.png)

How do I add digits per objects?

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mSzJnY87KF/

I want to do;

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUu8I.png)

what I have to do, I have tried many ways.

tnks for responses

Comment: digits in second img are keys and are strings!

Comment: you can find your anser in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447175/add-new-key-value-pair-into-json-in-php

Comment: the link you sent is not working for me ://

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54506489/edit): text instead of images please. Consecutive numeric keys will always be encoded as array. Unless `$i` starts at 1 / skips indexes / or simply is ordered is reverse, there won't be `"1":` object keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just need some thing like this

```php
$arr = [];
$arr["1"] = "content 1";
$arr["10"] = "content 2";
echo json_encode($arr);
```

do not use `array_push`